# How to Perform a Replace on Varbinary data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, varbinary

I've never had to do this before but I'm looking to do a SQL replace on varbinary data. I'm trying this but it's not successfully replacing, I think because it's treating the data as varchar and then cast back to varbinary. This stemmed from blank spaces at the end of these values but are not actual 'spaces' so RTRIM doesn't work in this scenario (bold below).

**Example of Data trying to change:**

> 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**0D0A090909090909090909090D0A090909090909090909090D0A090909090909090909090D0A09090909090909090909**

**Script:**

```
update digitalassetcontent 
set content = (CAST(REPLACE(content, '0D0A09090909090909090909', '') as varbinary(MAX)))
```

Comment: Try SELECT REPLACE(Content, 0x304430413039303930393039303930393039303930393039304430413039 , 0x) FROM digitalassetcontent  Does this give you the result u are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I was forgetting the 0x. Not sure why this needed and would like to understand. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update digitalassetcontent 
set content = REPLACE(content,0x0D0A09090909090909090909,0x)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the logic behind it. Anyway you could explain why the 0x is needed? Hexadecimal thing?

Comment: `0x` is a representation of a zero-length binary string, just like `''` is used to indicate a zero-length character string.