# Using Replace And Convert with varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, varbinary

I need a query that will find part of a string in a varbinary and remove on the requested part of the string

For example my table dbo.inventory_table has to columns CharacterIdx and Data.
Data is the target column which contains varbinary so for characteridx 101756 data is this

```
0x2105000000000000430000000000000000003C090000000000002C0100000200000000F83D09000000000000580200000400000000F83E09000000000000E80300000600000000F8
```

I want a query to find and remove

```
3C090000000000002C0100000200000000F83D09000000000000580200000400000000F83E09000000000000E80300000600000000F8
```

but leave

```
0x210500000000000043000000000000000000
```

Where CharacterIdx = 101756

I have tried

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Inventory_table]
SET Data = REPLACE(Data, '3C090000000000002C0100000200000000F83D09000000000000580200000400000000F83E09000000000000E80300000600000000F8', '')
WHERE CharacterIdx = 101756
```

But it gives me an error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>
> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed.
>
> Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I need the string to remain varbinary though.

Comment: As the second parameter of `REPLACE`, use `0x` instead of `''`. You should also don't put the first parameter between quotes; instead of this, prefix it with `0x`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494778/how-to-perform-a-replace-on-varbinary-data-in-sql

Comment: Those `000000` are going to cause you problems as well probably. As that is a NULL character. You might need `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to convert it back to varbinary as`replace`returns a`varchar`value from implicit conversion. Try this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Inventory_table]
SET Data = CAST(REPLACE(Data, 0x3C090000000000002C0100000200000000F83D09000000000000580200000400000000F83E09000000000000E80300000600000000F8, 0x) AS varbinary)
WHERE CharacterIdx = 101756
```

On my server this changes the value to:

```
0x210500000000000043000000000000000000
```

Comment: yea thats what im trying to get but that query didnt remove the rest, but it ran successfully

Comment: oh with the 0x revision? no let me try that now