# T-SQL Replace blank space

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encoding, replace

I have table where numbers are stored in `nvarchar` data type. The data looks as follows:

```
Numbers
---------
200
504 040
694 380
153 272
26 296
```

Now I'd like to get rid of the blank space in the numbers. However, `REPLACE(Numbers,' ','')` does not work as it seems the blank space is some kind of special "`blank space`".

So I tried to find any special character here using the function I found on SO ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655909/whats-the-best-way-to-identify-hidden-characters-in-the-result-of-a-query-in-sq)). Nothing happened, not any special character was found.

So the next step was exporting the record into `.csv` file and check data's encoding using TotalCMD. The result can be seen here:

[image]

Any ideas what could go wrong and how to replace those blank spaces? I think the Unicode encoding shows the problem, but I am lacking of knowledge in this area so I also can be wrong.

Update #1 - to show you more

The table looks like this:

```
Category    Number
-------------------
Cars           200
Cars       504 040
Cars       694 380
Cars       153 272
Cars        26 296
Bikes       50 000
Bikes       21 412
Bikes        8 541
```

Now I run the query:

```
SELECT 
    t.Category, REPLACE(t.Numbers,' ','')
FROM 
    tableMix AS t
WHERE 
    t.Category = 'Cars'

SELECT 
    t.Category, REPLACE(t.Numbers,' ','')
FROM 
    tableMix AS t
WHERE 
    t.Category = 'Bikes'
```

What is strange - the first query does not replace blank spaces for the `Cars` category, however the second query works without any problem for number values for `Bikes` category.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong because replace must work here. Please post your query.

Comment: I don't think so as with other numbers I have no problem and I am doing it in the same way. The query is posted already, just without SELECT and FROM clause. I still update the question for you, sec.

Comment: Try answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214848/how-do-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be it - the NCHAR(160).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make number from the nvarchar like this

```
SELECT 
    t.Category, cast(t.Numbers as int)
FROM 
    tableMix AS t
WHERE 
    t.Category = 'Cars'
```

Comment: You are unfortunately not able to do it. Also, the problem was already resolved, see comments in the question.