# issue with CASE combined with an OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case

```
SELECT  
    Siren,
    CASE    WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' AND Enseigne IS NOT NULL AND Enseigne <> '' --ok
                THEN 'Enseigne : ' + Enseigne
            WHEN (Sigle IS NULL OR Sigle ='')
                AND (Enseigne IS NULL OR Enseigne ='')
                THEN '' -- ok
            WHEN
                 (Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> '' ) THEN 'Sigle : ' + Sigle
            ELSE 'Sigle / Enseigne : ' + Sigle + ' / ' + Enseigne
        END as SigleEnseigne1,
        Sigle,
        Enseigne,
        Code_Juridique
        FROM    #JohnJack
```

The code is straightforward.

Issue lies with the third `when` as you can see below

[image]

I should have have nothing on my 4th and 5th line, yet it is giving me `Sigle :`

What I want is to have the column `SigleEnseigne1` on the 4th and 5th line , to be empty

Thanks for your insights

Comment: What are you expecting? The query seems to be acting as expected. Your query says that if Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> ''. Well, Sigle is not null, so it fulfills a part of the OR which means that it passes that criteria. That's how OR works.

Comment: Hi @tom-h, the issue is on line 4, the column `sigle` is not empty ...

Comment: It would probably be useful if you gave the expected output for each case (or row). I think that I know what you're trying to do, but it's easier if I don't have to guess.

Comment: @TomH, For the column `SigleEnseigne1` on line 1, it is giving me the desired results. On line 2 as well. On line 3, this is the expected results. On line 4, I should have `NULL` or `''` yet I'm having `Sigle :`and on line 5, I should have `NULL` or `''`, yet I'm having `Sigle :`

Comment: I believe that shadow's answer will get you what you need (or close to it), so I've given that an upvote. If his answer doesn't work for some reason then I'll take a stab at it if it seems clear enough why his isn't working.

Comment: Why not do this ISNULL(sigle,'') != '' instead of (Sigle IS NULL OR Sigle ='')

Comment: Of course it's not empty.   If Sigle is blank (''), it fulfills the 3rd WHEN in your CASE, because it's not null.   So you should expect it to give you `Sigle :`.

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman, issue is I've put `Sigle <> ''` ...

Comment: But you used an OR, so it doesn't matter if you have `Sigle <> ''`.   If Sigle is NOT NULL, then the whole OR expression is true, so the 3rd WHEN is returned by the CASE expression.   Did you mean to use AND instead of OR?

Comment: @TabAlleman If there is anything on the column `Sigle`, I want to see `Sigle :`. If there is nothing (e.g NULL OR ''), I want to see nothing

Comment: Then you should have used an AND instead of an OR.

Comment: @taballeman When doing that, I have `Sigle / Enseigne :  / SIM` for the 4th line

Comment: Thanks to the closing snipers, btw. I only got love for you :)

Comment: I think you must have some special invisible characters in your Sigle column then.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655909/whats-the-best-way-to-identify-hidden-characters-in-the-result-of-a-query-in-sq

Comment: Just @taballeman said... copy past a sigle cell to word, not notepad. Just curious.

Comment: @shadow There you go, sir -> http://pastebin.com/Z8Z2EZd1

Comment: Andy #JohnJack is a temporary table, right? How do you populate it? Maybe there is the problem. Wild guess if my initial hypothesis is true, about temp table

Comment: @shadow when I'm doing it through the normal table, I have the same issue. I need some time to figure it out. Tomorrow is Christmas here. I will take some time tomorrow morning to deal with that.

Comment: So you copy paste an empty cell and you get ADEME;5 ???

Comment: Ok my friend. Merry Christmas then!!! Hope you will come up with the solution!

Comment: @shadow, I've done that `SELECT Sigle,LEN(Sigle) FROM #JohnJack`

Comment: Me too. Fingers crossed. Merry Christmas to you as well, @shadow

Comment: Hi @shadow, I found my issue. I will post my query tomorrow as there is no internet at work today -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    Siren,
    CASE    WHEN ( Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' ) AND ( IsNull( Enseigne, '' ) <> '' )
                THEN 'Enseigne : ' + Enseigne

            WHEN ( IsNull( RTrim(LTrim(Sigle)), '') = '') AND ( IsNull( Enseigne, '' ) = '')
                THEN '' -- ok

            WHEN ( IsNull( RTrim(LTrim(Sigle)), '' ) <> '' ) 
                THEN 'Sigle : ' + RTrim(LTrim(Sigle))
            ELSE
                'Sigle / Enseigne : ' + IsNull( RTrim(LTrim(Sigle)), '' ) + ' / ' + Enseigne
        END as SigleEnseigne1,
        Sigle,
        Enseigne,
        Code_Juridique
        FROM    #JohnJack
```

Comment: Hi @shadow, nope. Sorry

Comment: So I guess that sigle is not null and also not empty string

Comment: That's the thing @shadow buddy, in sqlserver, it is giving me nothing. When I do a copy-paste and put the contents between quotes, I have nothing ...

Comment: nope @anton, the `ltrim` and `rtrim`are brilliant idea but something seems wrong in my datafield as it does not display what I want

Comment: try: select '-->'+sigle+'<--' from #JohnJack. sigle is text, right? (char, varchar etc)

Comment: @AndyK Do a `LEN(Sigle)` to verify if `Sigle` is anything other than whitespaces. Remember `LEN()` trims trailing whitespaces by default.

Comment: @shadow, it is giving me zero on `Sigle` ... #damn I'm losing my nerves

Comment: @AndyK Try using my variation with `LEN()`

Comment: @domenicr, I've just answered you

Comment: @AndyK I meant try using my answer, it is a variation of shadows answer. See below I posted it maybe 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @shadow many thanks for the help , last Wednesday. Lack of time yesterday eve in writing my answer (Lady , kids , cat etc ...)

Comment: @AndyK Not to mention my friend! Happy new year!

Comment: happy new year @shadow! :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides stating the obvious that a `(TRUE OR FALSE) = TRUE`
I would simplify and bullet proof the code by using `ISNULL()` and `LEN()`.

```
SELECT  
Siren,
CASE    WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' AND LEN(ISNULL(Enseigne,'')) > 0  --ok
            THEN 'Enseigne : ' + Enseigne
        WHEN (LEN(ISNULL(Sigle, '')) = 0)
            AND (LEN(ISNULL(Enseigne, '')) = 0) 
            THEN '' -- ok
        WHEN
             LEN(ISNULL(Sigle, '')) > 0 THEN 'Sigle : ' + Sigle
        ELSE 'Sigle / Enseigne : ' + ISNULL(Sigle, '') + ' / ' + ISNULL(Enseigne, '')
    END as SigleEnseigne1,
    Sigle,
    Enseigne,
    Code_Juridique
    FROM    #JohnJack
```

How would your code react if those fields contain whitespaces? `LEN` automatically trims trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Hi @domenicr , thanks for your input. Alas, it is giving me `Sigle / Enseigne :  / SIM` for the 4th line and `Sigle / Enseigne :  / MONTMORILLON CARBUANTS, SE MB ENERGIE FIOUL,` for the 5th line

Comment: @domenicr Nice approach! I can't understand what is wrong with sigle.

Comment: @AndyK To satisfy our curiosity please do a `SELECT LEN(Sigle), LENB(Sigle)` and tell us the results.

Comment: @domenicr, `len(sigle)` is giving me zero on the 4th and 5th lines, as I've put it in my examples. `lenb` is no longer supported in my sqlserver version

Comment: @AndyK My bad please do a SELECT LEN(Sigle), DATALENGTH(Sigle) and tell us the results

Comment: @domenicr until the 6th line, which is normal : I have zeros

Comment: @domenicr many thanks for the help , last Wednesday. Lack of time yesterday eve in writing my answer (Lady , kids , cat etc ...)

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing your probelm:

```
    (Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> '' ) THEN 'Sigle : ' + Sigle
```

...but that is only obvious because you state that you dont want this result. Other than that the code acts as would be expected.

The simplest solution would be to take out:

```
  'Sigle : ' + Sigle
```

but that may or may not be precisely what you are looking for. Based on the given information it is the solution but there is not an abundance of information to work off

If you are trying to get non null values to print then it should be an AND rather than an OR. When you use an OR it will return true if EITHER condition is true.

Comment: (Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> '' ) This line is checking for sigle not null OR sigle = any non empty string. In other words if sigle contains anything at all that line will print out

Comment: issue is there are nothing with I can see with my human eyes ... notepad++ is not showing anything either ...

Comment: What is sigle supposed to contain? and what is the desired output in each case? From my point of view it is difficult to tell why this is not the desired result.

Comment: try changing the OR to an AND

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have this `when`

```
        WHEN (Sigle IS NULL OR Sigle = '')
            AND (Enseigne IS NULL OR Enseigne ='')
            THEN '' -- ok
```

As what you want is SigleEnseigne1 to be `NULL` or `''` when Sigle is `NULL` or `''` don't you need this `when` instead

```
WHEN (Sigle IS NULL OR Sigle = '') THEN ''
```

There can also be the problem that Sigle is not the empty string and has whitespaces. You can use the `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions

Answer (score 0):

It took me the weekend but actually, I figured out My mistake.

Sorry for the mess

The answer is below

```
 SELECT  
 Siren,
 CASE    WHEN ( Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%' ) AND ( IsNull( Enseigne, '' ) <> '' )
             THEN 'Enseigne : ' + Enseigne
         WHEN ( IsNull( RTrim(LTrim(Sigle)), '') = '') AND ( IsNull( Enseigne, '' ) = '')
             THEN '' -- ok
         WHEN (Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> '') AND (Enseigne IS NULL OR Enseigne = '') 
             THEN 'Sigle : ' + RTrim(LTrim(Sigle))
         WHEN (Sigle IS NULL OR Sigle = '') AND (Enseigne IS NOT NULL OR Enseigne <> '') 
             THEN ''
         WHEN
             (Sigle IS NOT NULL OR Sigle <> '') AND (Enseigne IS NOT NULL OR Enseigne <> '') 
             THEN 'Sigle / Enseigne : ' + IsNull( RTrim(LTrim(Sigle)), '' ) + ' / ' + Enseigne
     END as SigleEnseigne1
     FROM    John_Jack
```

Have a great end of the year